# How do search k elements of n elements in O(k log n) time?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, math, time, complexity-theory

My approach was that log n means that we make a tree by dividing the array into 2 sets till we have all the elements separated then we will se if each element is in the array or not.
In this approach the time complexity should be O(n log n) because the last element could be in the last leaf.
What am I missing?
I found a solution but I didn't understand it.

[image]

Comment: it's called binary search, but you have to have an orderd array in order to make use of that

Comment: The question doesn't say that it's sorted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution you show is not for the problem you are trying to solve. In their context they can test if some group of cities is contaminated by what they call an "experiment" and want to know how few experiments they need to find exactly which **k** cities are contaminated. This is a theoretical situation and is most likely meant only as an exercise with no real life application.

In reality, you can't test if an array contains an element in less than **O(n)** time in the worst case, unless this array has some structure to it (for example being sorted). In particular, you can't test if an array contains **k** elements in **O(k log n)** time for **k = o(n / log(n))**, because in this case **k log n = o(n)**. This of course also means that it is impossible for constant **k**.

(But if **k** is of the same order as **n** then **O(k log n)** becomes **O(n log n)** and then you can resort to sorting your array).

If your array is sorted then you can perform **k** binary searches and achieve this runtime.

Comment: I thought it was the same.can you please help me understand the algorithm?

Comment: It is like they had an algorithm (call it **A**) which can test in constant time if some element in the array of cities is contaminated, and from that algorithm try to design a second algorithm (say **B**) to find **which**  cities are contaminated. They use divide and conquer to design **B** using **A**, where they only have to look in the subtrees that contain a contaminated city, thanks to algorithm **A**. And so the only leaves that they explore are the contaminated ones. This is just an exercise to learn techniques. But in real life, algorithm **A** doesn't exist, so you can't do that.

Comment: In real life, algorithm A is to mix the water from those cities together and send it to the lab as one sample to be analysed. Note that they ask for O(k log n) *experiments*, not O(k log n) time.

Answer (score 0):

Binary search uses that approach:

1. it takes an ascendent ordered array as input
2. goes to the middle element
3. if that's the element you are looking for, that's it
4. else :

   - middle element < the element searched -> to the same thing using as input array the right half of the array
   - middle element > the element searched -> to the same thing using as input array the left half of the array
5. Continue until or the element is been found, or the array size is 1

If the array is not sorted, there is no way you can find it in `k*log n`, at least `O(n)` just checking every element with the desired ones

Comment: I know what binary search is the problem is if I want to find k elements. for example if I have an array of {1,2,3,4} (n elements) and I want to find {2,3}  (k elements) in O(k log n)

Comment: exactly, just run binary search k times, but without the reorder, you can't use binary serach

Comment: actually, the solution doesn't explain anything